# How to download audios from soundcloud

Tags: angular, ionic2, storage, soundcloud, cordova-nativestorage

I  have an Ionic 2 app that can stream audios from SoundCloud.

This is how I do streaming:

```
public loadSelectedTrack(): void {

        SC.get('/tracks/' + this.audio.id, {
            filter: 'public'
        }).then((track) => {

            this.soundCloudCurrentTrack = track;
            this.playSelectedTrack();
        });
    }

    public playSelectedTrack(): void {
        SC.stream('/tracks/' + this.soundCloudCurrentTrack.id).then((player) => {


            this.togglePlayPause();

            player.on('buffering_start', () => {
                console.log('buffering...');
            });

            player.on('buffering_end', () => {
                console.log('party!');
                this.audioLoaded = true;
            });

            player.on('finish', () => {
                this.navCtrl.pop();
            });

            this.player = player;

            player.on('time', () => {
                this.updateTrackTime();
                this.updateTrackPercent();
            });

            this.saveUserData();

        });
    }
```

Now, I need to know how to download an audio and then, how to find it in the device.

I thought if I can download an audio, I can storage the id with [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/) or [NativeStorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/nativestorage/)

But I don't know if it is the best way to do that. Someone did it any time?

---

EDIT: Well, I've tried to download audios, but there is a problem. When I press the download button, I don't see anything. So if I go to the app folder I can see an audio file but it's broken because always have an 600bytes size, and I can't manually play it.

I wanted to see the progress, so after research I found to do that whit an event. So I've tried to show the progress temporaly with toast notifications, but it shows me "97".."98"... and then no more is happening. If I go to the app folder with my explorer, I see an audio file but broken. And it's no showing errors! 
This is the code:

```
public download(audio: any): void {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            console.log("Clicked to download: " + audio.id);

            let url = `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/${audio.id}/download?client_id=${this.SC_CLIENT_ID}`;

            let pathToSaveTo: string = '';

            if (this.platform.is('android')) {
                pathToSaveTo = cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + audio.id + '.wav';

                let fileTransfer = new Transfer();

                fileTransfer.onProgress(this.onProgress);

                fileTransfer.download(url, pathToSaveTo)
                    .then((entry) => {
                        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
                    }, (error) => {

                        let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
                            title: 'Error',
                            subTitle: error,
                            buttons: ['Accept']
                        });

                        prompt.present();
                    });
            }


        });

    }

    onProgress = (progressEvent: ProgressEvent) : void => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {

                let progress: any = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
                console.log(progress);

                let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: progress,
                  duration: 100
                });
                toast.present();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I just edited the post with my code, sorry

Comment: If you like to see, I added how i'm trying to download audios but with problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily download files using [Transfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/) module ionic 2 offers.
You should download the files to a different directory for different platforms, read the docs [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)
When downloading the file, it is really good to store data about the file for later usage.
You can use [Storage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/) to store whatever data you might need about the file (it's name for instance).
Then. depending on the platform, you can access this file, again, see the docs for *cordova-plugin-file*  for more details about file access.

Comment: Nice! I will research it..

Comment: I just edited my post. Can you see it, please? Thank you!